# Location Update not showing in my android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            LocationAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MyApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(viewModel: locationViewModel= viewModel()){
    val context= LocalContext.current
    val locationUtils=LocationUtils(context)
    LocationDisplay(viewModel,locationUtils = locationUtils, context =context )
}

@Composable
fun LocationDisplay(
    viewModel: locationViewModel,
    locationUtils: LocationUtils,
    context: Context
){

    val location =viewModel.location.value
    // request for permission. permission pop up shows
    val requestPermissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
        if (it[Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION]==true
            && it[Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION]==true
            ){
            //I have access the location
            locationUtils.requestLocationUpdates(viewModel)
        }else{
            //Ask for location
            val rationalRequired=ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                context as MainActivity,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )|| ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                context as MainActivity,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            )

            if (rationalRequired){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Location permission is required",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"go to the setting" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        if (location!=null){
            Text(text = "Your longitude: ${location.longitude} and Latitude: ${location.latitude}")
        }else{
            Text(text = "Location not found")
        }

        Button(onClick = {
            if (locationUtils.hasLocationPermission(context)){
                locationUtils.requestLocationUpdates(viewModel)

            }else{
                //request permission
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                    arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    )
                )
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Get location")
        }
    }
}
```

Location Data Class

```
package com.example.locationapp

data class LocationData(
    var latitude:Double,
    var longitude:Double
)
```

LocationViewModel

```
class locationViewModel:ViewModel(){

    //update location data
    private val _location= mutableStateOf<LocationData?>(null)
    var location: State<LocationData?> = _location

    fun updateLocation(locationData: LocationData){
        _location.value=locationData
    }
}
```

Location Utils

```
class LocationUtils(
    context:Context
) {
     // get and show the location
    //it retrieve the location
    private val _fusedLocationClient:FusedLocationProviderClient=
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")//use this because we can not use the fun without permission
    // update the location data in viewModel
    fun requestLocationUpdates(viewModel: locationViewModel){
        val locationCallback=object: LocationCallback(){
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                locationResult.lastLocation?.let {
                    val location = LocationData(it.latitude,it.longitude)
                    viewModel.updateLocation(location)
                }
            }
        }
        //build the location request
        val locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(
            Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,1000).build()

        // now we fused the data
        _fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
    }




    fun hasLocationPermission(context: Context):Boolean{
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}
```

When i click the button there is no location update showed. Instead off showing location it display a toast massege "Go to settings" even after location permission has been given. What i have to do for updating the location? What is wrong with my code please explain and give the corrected code.

Comment: If you set some breakpoints in mainactivity what is it saying? Does it see you have permissions or not? If yes but it’s still asking for permissions the logic needs to be updated. Otherwise when you click the update button what happens - is the click listener called, is the data updated, is the UI being updated?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure that the user enabled the general Location permission of the device.
You can check if the device has general Location permission turned on with this code:

```
private fun Context.isGpsLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
    val locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    return LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(locationManager)
}
```

If it returns false you should forward the user to the system setting with this code:

```
context.startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
```

And also i would recommend to register/unregister for location updates inside of an DisposableEffect:

```
if (allPermissionsGranted) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
        onDispose {
            fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your code not sure what is wrong but maybe you could use the library from google: https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/
It would make it a little bit easier to do the steps. Or at least after starting the activity you maybe just make sure to recheck if all permissions are granted and update an mutable state. So you can check in your code.